# Firefox UI Library

Tags: firefox, user-interface

What library does Firefox use for its user interface and can you use it in other applications?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XUL

http://www.mozilla.org/projects/xul/

and

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUL

Answer (score 6):

Firefox uses [XUL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUL) to define its user interface, and renders it using [Gecko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_(layout_engine)).

Since Gecko is open, you can very much use it to render your application, though I don't know how simple such an interface would be to implement.

Answer (score 5):

[XUL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUL)